# How to use configure Grunt to copy bower font files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower, font-awesome, wiredep

I'm using bower to install `bootstrap` and `font-awesome` packages, and use `Grunt` as a build solution.  I have `wiredep` configured to properly update my index.html file.  Everything works great.  The only problem I have is copying the font files to the `dist/` directory.

I realize that I can configure my grunt `copy:dist` target, but given that each package may use a different directory structure to store their fonts, it is challenging to have a single rule to copy the fonts.  Additionally, if these packages have the fonts listed in their `bower.json` files, isn't there a way to detect these fonts and copy them automatically?

Is there another Grunt plugin that I can use that recognizes the font files the same way `wiredep` recognizes the css/js files?

I've seen other posts on SO that relate to the same issue, but no official solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a bit old, but I use a plugin called grunt-bowercopy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bowercopy) to do most of my copying from bower packages. It may require a bit of manual configuration though, so it might not live up to your requirements.

Your bowercopy config could look something like this:

```
bowercopy: {
    // Global bowercopy options
    options: {
        runBower: true
    },
    // Move fonts from bower packages into font folder
    fonts: {
        options: { destPrefix: '/dist/fonts' },
        files: {
            '': 'fontawesome/fonts/*'
        }
    }
}
```

You could tweak the glob-pattern to simply move all font files in the bower_components directory, into some destination folder. That's a decent option if you don't like to manually add the path, for every bower package that includes fonts. I like the "manual labor" though.